# After creating a new user in a SQL Server database, the user is able to create and drop tables. Why?

Tags: sql-server, access-rights

I have a huge problem with rights of new users of my SQL Server database. The new user cannot see any tables but is still able to drop them or create new tables.

Code to create the user:

```
--Code Start
--This is how I instantiate the new user:

CREATE LOGIN userName WITH PASSWORD 'password';
CREATE USER userName FOR LOGIN userName;

--Furthermore, the user get some roles. So that the user can do at least something:

CREATE ROLE roleExample;
GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON dbo.exampleTable TO roleExample;
SP_ADDROLEMEMBER roleExample, userName;

--Code End
```

In my opinion, the new User should only be able to operate on the exampleTable now. But as I said, the user is also able to create and drop tables.

That's why, I added some constraints to the role, the new user gets:

```
DENY CREATE TABLE TO roleExample AS dbo;
```

This did not help either. The User is still able to create tables in dbo.

This problem is btw. not related to a specific schema. The new user can create and drop tables in any schema.

I guess that new users are allowed to create or drop tables by default. Sadly, I do not know how to change it.

I hope you guys can help me.

Attached is an example, where you can see that the user does not know the schema, where a new table should be created. Nevertheless, the schema exists and after executing this statement, the table is created. The error-message just says that this table is already created, because I executed this statement twice. Still, the user is not able to see its own created table in SQL Server Management Studio.

[User does not know schema, but still can create tables in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEF2w.png)

Comment: I think that there's something wrong with either your [guest] account or your database's security settings.  Although this question is allowed here, in this case I think that you would get better answers at https://dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Check that you have the latest Service Pack or Cumulative Update for your SQL Server version, if not then update it: https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/

Comment: OK, I'm a little bit rusty, but most likely someone has granted these permissions to the `Public` role in your database. so you may want to look there.

Comment: The "does not know schema" thing is likely just as intellisense doesn't automatically refresh when new objects are created. You can't read anything into the red squiggly line there unless you have refreshed the intellisense cache

Comment: @RBarryYoung This sounds like a possible solution. Hopefully, I will find out next week. Sadly, I don not have time this week anymore…

Comment: @MartinSmith First, I thought about this, too. But this is not the case here. Even after disconnecting and connecting again, the schema and created tables are not visible.

Comment: SP_ADDROLEMEMBER has been deprecated for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so there's several things that it might be, but by far the most likely is that someone has granted some database permission(s) to the `public` role or to some AD group that your users are all in.  (Also possible, but less likely is that something similar has been done to the server permissions).

To check for database permissions open SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), right-click on your database in the Object Explorer pane and select "Properties".  Then in the Database Properties window click the "Permissions" page from the list on the upper-left.

If there are any database permissions granted to any Users or Roles, they should appear in the upper listbox.  If Public is in there click it to see if has been granted any database-wide permissions.  All users have the Public role, so anything granted here is automatically granted to all users.

If that isn't it, then check any other roles listed in the upper listbox.  Also check any users that look like they might be AD Groups because these work like DB roles except that SQL Server cannot administer them, nor tell who's in a specific group from these interfaces.

If you don't find anything here, then repeat this for the Server Permissions also.